# Can I hide or dismiss this music player?

Tags: iphone, ios

I’m listening to an audiobook with the Audible app, and while it’s playing (and for a while after) this playback controller shows up above the Notification Center.

[image]

However, because of the small screen on my phone (iPhone SE) all of my notifications are obscured. I would prefer if this music widget wasn’t shown, because I can easily control audio from the control centre or in the app instead. I’m using iOS 13.

Comment: Can you just delete the app that is doing this?

Comment: @jmh Audible is the app that’s doing this. I want to play the audio from the app, just not have it take over my whole lock screen.